# T4 code generator to Java like Typewriter

Tags: java, c#, rest, t4, typewriter

I am using the [Typewriter](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/) extension in Visual Studio. I am thinking of something like this to generate Java model classes. The main problem is how to introduce models of REST API web service to the client developers. For the Android developers I want to produce Java files representing my server side models and serve these files as a web service for them. Is there something like Typewriter for Java or any better solutions for this problem?

Comment: 1. U can produce files for Java system with tools in .NET, these are only text files I dont know ready to go templates exist, maybe require own work. 2. If want natural Java, libraries line Velocity, WebMacro, StringTemplate have good proven tradition in similar generation